# WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound

Tags: java, spring

Tengo este error cuando quiero correr un proyecto de java con spring

> WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [/utm/] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'springDispatcher'

Adjunto dos imágenes que representan en problema

El archivo **web.xml** no lo modifique, pero es el único donde aparece `DispatcherServlet`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>Spring Web App</display-name>

<!-- Definición del Root Spring Container compartido por todos los Servlets
    y Filtros -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/rootContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Crea el Spring Container compartido por todos los Servlets y Filtros -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Procesa las solicitudes a la aplicación -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servletContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Configuración JSP -->
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/includes/base.jsp</include-prelude>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<!-- Configuración de la Sesión -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<distributable />
```

**Archivo HomeController.java**

```
package me.jmll.utm;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
  * Handles requests for the application home page.
*/
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private HelloService helloService;
    private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simplemente selecciona el template home.jsp para
 * interpretarlo como respuesta
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}

/**
 * Crea un Response Body con un servicio en especÃ­fico.
 */
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"name"})
public String homeName(Locale locale, Model model, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! {} The client locale is {}.", name, locale);

    return helloService.getHello(name);
}

/* 4(a) Inyectar HelloService en HomeController */
@Inject
public void setHelloService(HelloService helloService){
    this.helloService = helloService;
 }
}
```

**Server**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Console**

```
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CS_13304' did not find a matching property.
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         8.5.32.0
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 10
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            10.0
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          amd64
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:       C:\Users\Santiago\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Santiago\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Santiago\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
oct 02, 2018 1:46:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: 
[C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\xampp\php;C:\composer;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\system32;;.]

oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 1088 ms
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
oct 02, 2018 1:46:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
oct 02, 2018 1:46:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
oct 02, 2018 1:46:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
oct 02, 2018 1:46:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
oct 02, 2018 1:46:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:46:22.667 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
13:46:22.973 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:46:22 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
13:46:23.230 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/rootContext.xml]
13:46:23.630 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13:46:23.749 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1078 ms
oct 02, 2018 1:46:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher'
13:46:23.783 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher': initialization started
13:46:23.792 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue 
Oct 02 13:46:23 CDT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:46:23.793 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servletContext.xml]
13:46:24.105 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13:46:24.490 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:46:23 CDT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:46:24.571 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Oct 02 13:46:23 CDT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:46:24.667 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
13:46:24.756 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher': initialization completed in 972 ms
oct 02, 2018 1:46:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
oct 02, 2018 1:46:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
oct 02, 2018 1:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 14481 ms
13:46:25.649 [http-nio-8090-exec-2] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/utm/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún controlador (@Controller) creado?

Comment: Si @PabloLozano

Comment: tu URL tiene /utm/... así que asumo que ese debería ser el nombre del módulo desplegado en tu servidor. ¿Puedes comprobar que es así? No es el nombre del proyecto. Haciendo doble click en el servidor, en Eclipse, deberías poder ver los módulos desplegados.

Comment: @PabloLozano Añadí una nueva imagen espero que de respuesta a lo que me preguntas

Comment: Tienes dos métodos mapeados con la misma dirección (`"/"`), quizá eso te esté causando conflictos. En lugar de poner imágenes copia el log que tienes en consola al arrancar Tomcat... lo mismo ahí vemos alguna pista

Comment: Parece que estás intentando de acceder a /utm y lo unico que tenes mapeado es "/", osea el home. Estas haciendo un request a una URI que no existe, de ahí el error! Si querés acceder a /utm tenés que crear la ruta con @Controller y después hacer que esa ruta devuelva lo que necesitas ...